# invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int*'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to recreate the vector class in C++

I obtain this error int the function at();

invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int*'

Isn't it possible to return a pointer as address even if the function is supposed to return a reference?

the code looks like:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
public:

   explicit Vector(int initSize = 0);
   Vector(const Vector & rhs) throw (std::bad_alloc);
   ~Vector();
   const Vector & operator=(const Vector & rhs) throw (std::bad_alloc);
   void resize(int newSize);
   void reserve(unsigned int newCapacity);
   bool empty() const;
   int size() const;
   int capacity() const;
   T & operator[](int index);
   const T & operator[](int index) const;
   T & at(int index) throw (std::out_of_range);
   void push_back(const T & x) throw (std::bad_alloc);
   T pop_back();
   const T & back() const;
   typedef T * iterator;
   typedef const T * const_iterator;
   iterator insert(iterator it, const T& x) throw (std::bad_alloc);
   iterator begin();
   const_iterator begin() const;
   iterator end();
   const_iterator end() const;

private:
   int theSize;
   unsigned int theCapacity; 
   T * objects; 
};
#include "vector.hpp"
#endif /* VECTOR_HPP_ */

template<typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int initSize):theSize
(initSize),theCapacity(128),objects(0)
{

}

typename Vector<T>::iterator Vector<T>::begin()
{
    return objects;
}

template<typename T>
T & Vector<T>::at(int index) throw (std::out_of_range)
{
    //if (index<=theSize)
        return (begin()+index);
}

int main() 
{
        Vector<int>* vec1=new Vector<int>(4);
    cout<<vec1->at(2)<<endl;
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: You should be using `Vector<int> vec1(4);` in `main`.

Comment: Just from the guts (tl;dr;): Propably a superflous `&` or missing `*` somewhere ..

Comment: `at()` returns a *reference*. `begin() + index` is pointer arithmetic, evaluating to an *address*. You need to return `*(begin() + index)`, and I highly advise you range-check that first, and throw an exception if its out of bounds. And note, unless you want to support *negative* offsets, and I can't imagine you do, your index parameter should be *unsigned*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `begin()+index` is of pointer type; you need to add a dereference to make it a reference:

```
template<typename T>
T & Vector<T>::at(int index) throw (std::out_of_range)
{
    return *(begin()+index);
}
```

Note that this may not be safe, because operations that re-allocate `objects` would invalidate the reference obtained through the `at()` function.